# What are the major differences between Facebook's ELF RF framework and TensorFlows "Agents"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I recently read a few papers, especially

- [ELF: An Extensive, Lightweight, and Flexible
  Research Platform for Real-time Strategy Games](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6859-elf-an-extensive-lightweight-and-flexible-research-platform-for-real-time-strategy-games.pdf)
- [TensorFlow Agents:  Efficient Batched Reinforcement Learning in TensorFlow](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.02878.pdf)

As far as I can understand, ELF uses two separate environments (C++ and Python), because they say

> Most existing RL environments (OpenAI Gym, ...) provide Python interfaces which wrap only single game instances.  As a result, parallelism needs to be built in Python when applying modern RL methods. However, thread-level parallelism in Python can only poorly utilize multi-core processors, due to the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). Process-level parallelism will also introduce extra data exchange overhead between processes and increase complexity to framework design.  In contrast, our parallelism is achieved with C++ threads for better scaling on multi-core CPUs.

The team from DeepMind (which developed the TensorFlow Agent lib) on the other hand explain it as such:

> Our implementation is completely defined within the TensorFlow graph.
>   First, we parallelize the forward pass of the neural network by vectorizing the
>   agent computation to produce a batch of actions from a batch of observations. [...] Using a batch size during inference allows us to leverage the internal
>   thread pool of the TensorFlow session, or hardware accelerators such as GPUs and
>   TPUs.

So, how are those two different? Sure, ELF uses C++, because they say doing it in Python is tedious and not efficient. TF agents uses "vectorization" and runs everything in the TensorFlow graph. I know, TF uses C underneath and a lot of Protobuffers to communicate data between Python & the underlying C code.

So did FB with their ELF just reinvent the wheel or did they do something else that is clever and the TF team didn't adopt?